# Elasticsearch Boosting Search Terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index that I am trying to search for matches based on multiple fields (title and description). If a particular term shows up in the title I want to be able to boost the score by 2*original score. If it is in description it should remain the original score. I am a bit confused by the elasticsearch documentation. Can anyone help me adjust the following query to reflect this logic?

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "string",
            "fields": ["title","description"]
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add `^2` to get a boost on the field you want:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "string",
            "fields": ["title^2","description"]
         }
     }
}
```